# How to use Oovoo SDK in android application?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am trying to add video calling functionality into my android app using the Oovoo SDK but I've never done anything related to audio or video calling.  I've read the [developers guide](http://developer.oovoo.com/docs) but I still have a hard time understanding how the methods all fit together.

What would be the best way to approach this?　Is there another SDK that has an more in-depth explanation for a beginner?

Answer (score 0):

You can contact to ooVoo SDK support , they will help you for free.